# Syntax error when creating schema for hsqldb

Tags: sql, syntax-error, database-schema, hsqldb

I´m trying to create a new schema and some tables, but I´m having a problem when I try to alter the recently created tables in order to set the foreing keys. The error that I am getting is that

> "Alter" word wasn´t expected at this point

(if I remove the alter statement the scripts works, and if a do the alter after executing the creation of tables and schema it works too, but I need everything to work as a whole). I´m using HSQL Database Manager.

```
CREATE SCHEMA TEST2 
CREATE TABLE TEST2.T1 (ID_T1 bigint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1), CODE varchar(200), ID_T2 integer NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID_T1))
CREATE TABLE TEST2.T2 (ID_T2 integer GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1), DESCRIPTION varchar(200), PRIMARY KEY (ID_T2))
ALTER TABLE TEST2.T1 ADD CONSTRAINT FKT1333520 FOREIGN KEY (ID_T2) REFERENCES TEST2.T2(ID_T2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the constraint in table definition. It needs a semicolon at the end

```
CREATE SCHEMA TEST2 AUTHORIZATION DBA
CREATE TABLE TEST2.T1 (ID_T1 bigint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1), CODE varchar(200), ID_T2 integer NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID_T1))
CREATE TABLE TEST2.T2 (ID_T2 integer GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1), DESCRIPTION varchar(200), PRIMARY KEY (ID_T2),
CONSTRAINT FKT1333520 FOREIGN KEY (ID_T2) REFERENCES TEST2.T2(ID_T2));
```

Comment: Hi! thanks :), that works, but in fact i posted a resumed example of my script. I have a lot of other tables with foreign keys and im finding difficult to implement the creation by specifying the primary keys in the table creation...